# Geary 0.11 doesn't work

Tags: pantheon-mail

I use geary 0.10 - working correctly - for 4 accounts

after update on Geary 0.11 - working only the first account - others are visible, indicate a new messages, but can't open it, read, resend or create new

for now, I downgrade on Geary 0.10

Have You got any idea for solution?
Thank You, Sonny

Comment: Same here!
just posted a question about this 'bug' https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11211/cannot-select-folders-mailboxes-geary-0-11-3 ps: i updated from geary 0.10.0 (native in freya) because i cant add outlook imap accounts.

Answer (score 1):

you upgraded the version geary with a PPA right?
If that is the case you just need install ppa-purge, is an utility that remove a ppa and revert the changes that the ppa made to the system

- first, install ppa-purge with this command

  `sudo apt install ppa-purge`
- after, use ppa-purge to remove the ppa of geary 0.11 (I'm using the PPA that is shown in all the webs with the note of geary update for this example, please check if is the same that you used), this is the command.

  `sudo ppa-purge ppa:geary-team/releases`

just wait until the process end and your geary  would be the default of elementary.

Comment: Alexander, thanks but doesn't work. I use Loki,  and Geary 0.11 working perfectly.